# How to remove highlighting when TextField is selected in SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to make a custom `TextField`. There is this highlight that shows up when it is tapped on macOS. I don't want it to be there. Below images demonstrates what I mean:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

The first image shows when the `TextField` is not currently selected. The second image shows when the `TextField` is selected. You will notice on the second image there is this dark highlighting that appears.

How can I get rid of this? Code is below:

```
struct CustomView: View {
    
    @State private var prompt = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            TextField("Prompt", text: $prompt, axis: .vertical)
                .lineLimit(10)
                .padding(4)
                .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.28))
                .cornerRadius(4)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, `TextField` on macOS is extremely limited and inflexible. I always end up creating a wrapper around AppKit components for text entry.

Comment: You can try `TextEditor(text:)`.